# C# PictureBox.Image

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

the following is an example of test code, it maybe not be completely correct:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXCOL; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAXROW; j++)
            {
                HomeArrayPicBox[i, j].Image  = Properties.Resources.scan;
            }
        }
```

my issue is instead of all pictureboxes displaying the same picture, i need to increment the image also. e.g. Properties.Resources.scan1, Properties.Resources.scan2 ...

please adive how best to achive this.

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an object from a Resources file by name like this:

```
HomeArrayPicBox[i, j].Image = 
    (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Scan" + i);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this before...just curious, do you need to do a typecast here when pulling the object from the resourcemanager?

Comment: i get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I forgot to include `(Image)`.  Try it again now.

Answer (score 0):

Make scan an array of image resources, and on each iteration, determine the correct index of that array to populate the picture box with.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all image object you need in an array.
The length of this array should be MAXCOL * MAXROW.
I assume you have the same number of images as boxes? 
Than you could iterate trough this array.